# Acquiring username of IP on the same network

Tags: windows, networking, cmd, ip, wmic

I am trying to solve an issue of using the IP of a computer on the same network I am on to find out who is logged into that device. I am very new to networking.

Currently I am running an IP Scan on the network to see which IPs are occupied (Angry IP Scanner). I'll then use the following command:

```
wmic.exe /node:"172.28.1.100" ComputerSystem Get UserName
```

to try and view the user name of the device. I am getting the error of:

```
Node - 172.28.1.100
ERROR:
Description = Access is denied.
```

I am trying to wrap my head around where the access error is. It shouldn't be a network problem since we're on the same one. Can the ComputerSystem command only be used on a device without security credentials?

I am using a windows 7 device. Again I am very new to networking.

Comment: You might want to look at how this is done at https://p0w3rsh3ll.wordpress.com/2012/02/03/get-logged-on-users/

Comment: This is a really great post, thanks for linking it. Although it looks like this script only returns the information for a user logged into the local device. Is there a parameters to get this same information for an IP on the same network?

Answer (score 0):

Since WMI allows you to fully control a host, I would assume that you don´t have enough admin privileges to acess all hosts.

This article ([WMI Remote "Access Denied"](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/4f33837b-1cb1-4648-85b1-3ba87cbfe93e/wmi-remote-access-denied?forum=winserverManagement)) gives a step-by-step to ensure all permissions are set adequately (see first answer).

C.